# Python - Determine a correct base url when the url may be rewritten

Tags: python, url-rewriting, web-scraping, base-url

My usual way to find out a full url is:

```
resp = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.example.com')
base_url = resp.geturl()
# find the wanted (relative) url in the resp by using BeautifulSoup4
full_url = urljoin(base_url, relative_url)
```

However, for some websites such as http://www.titanquest.net/tq-forum/forums/72-Underlord, the base_url and so full_url are wrong because the url is rewritten (I assume) as illustrated below:

```
>>> full_url
'http://www.titanquest.net/tq-forum/forums/72-Underlord'
>>> relative_url
'threads/43456-Epic-items?s=26260c54fd856499bff7a57e3c7ceb94'
>>> urljoin(full_url, relative_url)
'http://www.titanquest.net/tq-forum/forums/threads/43456-Epic-items?s=26260c54fd856499bff7a57e3c7ceb94'
```

The correct url should be:

```
http://www.titanquest.net/tq-forum/threads/43456-Epic-items?s=26260c54fd856499bff7a57e3c7ceb94
```

My question is how to produce the correct base_url and therefore full_url.

Answer (score 2):

Your browser normally indeed uses the location of the current page as the basis for relative URLs, and your use of `urljoin` simulates that behaviour correctly.

However, if the HTML returned contains a [`<base />` tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.4), the browser uses the url named by that tag as the basis for resolving relative URLs. The `<base />` tag is part of the HTML head.

You'll need to parse the response of `http://www.titanquest.net/tq-forum/forums/72-Underlord` to determine if there is such a tag, then use *its* value instead of the URL of the page instead to determine a relative URL. The `<base href="link" />` link value *itself* could be relative, in which case you'd have to make that absolute first based on the document location.

In this particular case, the web page contains such a `<base />` tag:

```
<base href="http://www.titanquest.net/tq-forum/" /><!--[if IE]></base><![endif]-->
```